# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/ModelDriven

Tags: jsp, struts2, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting this error while running login application in struts .Every required jar is installed as I saw many solutions of `missing jar xwork-core-2.3.24.1`.I did this solution but still getting same error.

I am pasting my `struts.xml` and `web.xml` file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                          id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>501</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Make sure that is loaded in the classpath?

Comment: You don't have all your dependencies. What are you using for dependency management?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).